# Search through multiple lists, but have functions that do that in parts

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework table of Addresses. I'm building a Repository that would allow me to search for an Address by either parts of the Address or the whole address.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public class AddressRepository : Repository<Address>
{
    public List<Address> GetByAddress(string street, string city, string state, string zip)
    {
        return DbSet
            .Where(address => address.Street.Contains(street))
            .Where(address => address.City.Contains(city))
            .Where(address => address.State.Contains(state))
            .Where(address => address.Zip.Contains(zip))
            .ToList();
    }

    public List<Address> GetByStreet(string street)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(address => address.Street.Contains(street)).ToList();
    }

    public List<Address> GetByCity(string city)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(address => address.Street.Contains(city)).ToList();
    }

    public List<Address> GetByState(string state)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(address => address.Street.Contains(state)).ToList();
    }

    public List<Address> GetByZip(string zip)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(address => address.Street.Contains(zip)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my Repository base class:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; }

    protected Repository()
    {
        DbSet = _applicationDbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm thinking that in my `GetByAddress` function I should be calling my `GetByStreet/City/State/Zip` functions instead of repeating their code.

I haven't quite figured out how to do that, so any help or suggestions regarding that would be great.

As a side question: In my `Repository` class I have a `GetAll` function that returns the whole DbSet as a list, should I be calling `GetAll().Where(...)` instead of calling `DbSet.Where(...)`?

Comment: I suggest that you show your `Repository` base class as well.

Comment: I've updated the post to include it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you don't use a repository at all. You already have a library that handles abstracting the database. You don't need the repository abstraction. And if you need some kind of abstraction, use a query object.

Some extensions are handy to build the query:

```
public static class AddressQueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Address> WhereStreetContains(this IQueryable<Address> query, string street)
    {
        return query.Where(address => address.Street.Contains(street));
    }

    public static IQueryable<Address> WhereCityContains(this IQueryable<Address> query, string city)
    {
        return query.Where(address => address.City.Contains(city));
    }

    public static IQueryable<Address> WhereStateContains(this IQueryable<Address> query, string state)
    {
        return query.Where(address => address.State.Contains(state));
    }

    public static IQueryable<Address> WhereZipContains(this IQueryable<Address> query, string zip)
    {
        return query.Where(address => address.Zip.Contains(zip));
    }
}
```

These can be combined however you want:

```
var addresses = DbSet
    .WhereStreetContains(street)
    .WhereCityContains(city)
    .WhereZipContains(zip)
    .Where(x => x.State == null)
    .ToList();
```

Some reading regarding repositories and ORMs.

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/09/20/limiting-your-abstractions/
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/
https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Comment: Sorry for such a slow reply, it's been busy a time. The idea of leaving repositories in favor of Query objects is interesting and I'd have to dig into that some more. Thanks!